# If condition on Spinner drop-down list

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

I made a drop-down list using spinner but now I want and a specific message to display when a certain value is selected along with an EditText when a certain keyword is entered. I attempted using if condition but it didn't work. The scenario is like this: When the user input their `age` over 18 and selects "Yes" from the drop-down `hire`, a certain message will appear, both conditions must be satisfied

```
 public void stan(View hiring){
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> hire=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.decide, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        hire.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(hire);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String decide =spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        int age= Integer.parseInt(aged.getText().toString());
        if(age>18 && spinner.equals("Yes")){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Ok, go eat cabbage sauce",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"no",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void stan(View hiring){
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> hire=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.decide, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        hire.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(hire);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String decide =spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int age= Integer.parseInt(aged.getText().toString());
                if(age>18 && decide.equals("Yes")){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Ok, go eat cabbage sauce",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"no",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: It produces this error:

error: no suitable method found for makeText(<anonymous OnItemSelectedListener>,String,int)
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Ok, go eat cabbage sauce",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         ^
    method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemSelectedListener> cannot be converted to Context)
    method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemSelectedListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: use class context in toast, that is `<Classname>.this`

Answer (score 0):

Use **`spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()`**

Finally, Your condition will be

```
if(age>18 && spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Yes")){
             Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this,"Ok, go eat cabbage sauce",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
             Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this,"no",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: @Acesif May i know your activity name?

Comment: It produces this error: no suitable method found for makeText(<anonymous OnItemSelectedListener>,String,int) Toast.makeText(this,"Ok, go eat cabbage sauce",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ^ method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemSelectedListener> cannot be converted to Context) method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemSelectedListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: @Acesif you should use Proper activity name instead of `this`. Check my edited answer

Comment: @Acesif Solved this yet?